# virtualenvwrapper on mountain lion

Tags: python, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

Following this guide http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

I have a fresh install of mountain lion (i.e. not upgrading)

Ran

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
mkdir -p $DEV_HOME
```

Successfully
But when I run this line:
    source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

I get **-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory**

Is this just stored in a different location?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

The way I found it was to see where `pip install virtualenvwrapper` was putting all the files

(You can run it twice, pip will recognize they already exist)

Answer (score 6):

Should be in `/usr/local/share/python/virtualenvwrapper.sh`.

If it's not, try looking for it with `find`:

```
$ find / -name virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Or try reinstalling it and looking at where `pip` puts the scripts:

```
$ pip install -U --force-reinstall virtualenvwrapper

Downloading/unpacking virtualenvwrapper
...
...
changing mode of /usr/local/share/python/virtualenvwrapper.sh to 755    -- aha!
...
```

Comment: not there either, usr/local/share/python doesn't exist however /usr/lib/python2.7 exists

Comment: Just look for it then — `find /usr -name virtualenvwrapper.sh`. Or reinstall and pay close attention to what `pip` does (it changes mode of scripts to 755 and tells you the full path).

Answer (score 0):

On El Capitan I found virtualenvwrapper.sh at

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```